# How to transmit images from a camera?

Tags: wifi, gscam, camera, image, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I intend to public images from a wifi camera on a topic, i tried to use usb_cam but I think it does not support wifi, so i tried to download the gscam package but it is not available for indigo, what should I try? any ideas?

thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201633/how-to-transmit-images-from-a-camera?/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-24**:
Isn't this a duplicate of [How do I capture images from a wifi camera?](http://answers.ros.org/question/201588/how-do-i-capture-images-from-a-wifi-camera/)?

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2015-01-24**:
actually no, I found out that gscam was the right tool, but it is not available for indigo, i am asking if anyone knows a way to publish images from a wifi camera on a topic similar to gscam, or at least a package that allows me to do that, it can be so difficult but i do not get any answers

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2015-01-24**:
i am new at this, could you please explain my how to do that? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaict, `gscam` just hasn't been released for Indigo, but that doesn't mean you can't build it yourself. According to [gscam/issues/17](https://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam/issues/17), it should compile and work fine.

---

Edit: In general the process to build from source is something like:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/your/catkin_ws/src
cd $HOME/your/catkin_ws/src

git clone http://url/to/git/repository.git

cd $HOME/your/catkin_ws
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

# do what rosdep wants you to do (but use common sense, obviously)
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src

catkin_make
```

See also [catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). And replace `$HOME/your/catkin_ws` and `http://url/to/git/repository.git` with the real path and URL.

**note**: I have not tested this for `gscam`, but the process should be similar. It could be that `gscam` needs some tweaks/fixes to build under Indigo.

If you haven't, I recommend you follow the [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), as that will familiarise you with much of the terminology and commands, and make things like follow up tutorials (and the Answers on this site) much easier to understand.

---

> It seems to work properly thanks a lot, However still i get errors when i try to recieve images from a wifi camera [..]

Edit2: If the `gscam` pkg builds and runs, then you would probably need to figure out what the exact `GSCAM_CONFIG` environment variable is you need to access your phone's camera. See [wiki.ros.org/gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) for more information. You should be able to use any tutorial on Gstreamer to figure out how to exactly configure it, and use that knowledge to configure `gscam`.

> ( i ve been trying with my phone connected as a cam)

If it is an Android device, you might be interested in the [ROS Android Sensors Driver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.sensors_driver&hl=en). You can just install that on your phone, and start streaming images. No need for `gscam`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2015-01-25**:
it seems to work properly thanks a lot,
However still i get errors when i try to recieve images from a wifi camera( i ve been trying with my phone connected as a cam) maybe it would work with a normal wifi camera?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usb_cam and gscam nodes are for retrieving images from a camera connected to your computer using USB. You'll need a different driver for a network-connected camera.

(see: http://answers.ros.org/question/201588/how-do-i-capture-images-from-a-wifi-camera/ )

**EDIT**

It might be possible to find a gstreamer plugin which can talk to your camera, in which case the gscam driver might be appropriate. If so, see @gvdhoorn 's answer.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1